# awk script for finding smallest value from column

Tags: awk

I am beginner in `AWK`, so please help me to learn it. I have a text file with name `snd` and it values are

```
1 0 141
1 2 223
1 3 250
1 4 280
```

I want to print the entire row when the third column value is minimu

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should do it:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {line = $0; min = $3}
     NR > 1 && $3 < min {line = $0; min = $3}
     END{print line}' file.txt
```

**EDIT**:

What this does is:

- Remember the 1st line and its 3rd field.
- For the other lines, if the 3rd field is smaller than the min found so far, remember the line and its 3rd field.
- At the end of the script, print the line.

Note that the test `NR > 1` can be skipped, as for the 1st line, `$3 < min` will be false.  If you know that the 3rd column is always positive (not negative), you can also skip the `NR == 1 ...` test as `min`'s value at the beginning of the script is zero.

**EDIT2**:

This is shorter:

```
awk 'NR == 1 || $3 < min {line = $0; min = $3}END{print line}' file.txt
```

Comment: `awk 'NR==1 || $3 < min { line = $0; min = $3}; END {print line}' file.txt`

Comment: Yes Mark, quicker than me (I was doing the edit at the same time you post the comment).

Comment: **+1**. Somehow I missed reading this before I posted my (almost identical) answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer,it works for the text file which contains only two rows.not working for multi row valued files.so please give me that code

Answer (score 8):

You don't need `awk` to do what you want. Use `sort`

```
sort -nk 3 file.txt | head -n 1
```

Results:

```
1 0 141
```

Comment: **+1**.  Works perfectly ... except that it probably takes more resources than the awk command, because `sort` needs to store all the input in memory (or write to temp files), whereas awk handles things in a much more efficient pipe.

Answer (score 3):

I think `sort` is an excellent answer, unless for some reason what you're looking for is the awk logic to do this in a larger script, or you want to avoid the extra pipes, or the purpose of this question is to learn more about awk.

```
$ awk 'NR==1{x=$3;line=$0} $3<x{line=$0} END{print line}' snd
```

Broken out into pieces, this is:

- `NR==1 {x=$3;line=$0}` -- On the first line, set an initial value for comparison and store the line.
- `$3<x{line=$0}` - On each line, compare the third field against our stored value, and if the condition is true, store the line.  (We could make this run only on `NR>1`, but it doesn't matter.
- `END{print line}` -- At the end of our input, print whatever line we've stored.

You should read [`man awk`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=awk) to learn about any parts of this that don't make sense.

Comment: friends you gave me the code for finding minimum value from a text file.. thanks for that.... that code executed correctly only in terminal.. i want to execute that code with in awk program.so please help me for tha

Comment: The awk program in this answer is the part between the single quotes.  If not from a shell, how do you want to run the program?

Comment: thanks for the answer,it works for the text file which contains only two rows.not working for multi row valued files.so please give me that code

Comment: The code I provided is not limited to 2 rows of input.  If you're seeing that behaviour, then you're doing something odd with it.  But you've already picked an answer that works for you.

Comment: sorry for the late reply,i want to write this command as a awk file and execute it in a teminal.it means i want this code with in the begin{} end{} blocks.i tried like this BEGIN { NR==1{x=$3;line=$0} $3<x{line=$0} END{print line}} and executed it on terminal using awk -f filename.awk snd.but it didn't work.please tell me what is wrong in this code

Comment: @user1779084 - You have code that needs help?  That's great!  That's what we're here for!  If it's related to this question, please [edit your question to include it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13099202/edit).  Or, since this question was already answered to your satisfaction by jfgagne, you could [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with your code, and we'll answer it there.

Answer (score 3):

a short answer for this would be:

```
sort -k3,3n temp|head -1
```

since you have asked for awk:

```
awk '{if(min>$3||NR==1){min=$3;a[$3]=$0}}END{print a[min]}' your_file
```

But i prefer the shorter one always.

Comment: thanks for the answer,it works for the text file which contains only two rows.not working for multi row valued files.so please give me that code

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the smallest value in any column , let say last column

```
awk '(FNR==1){a=$NF} {a=$NF < a?$NF:a} END {print a}'
```

this will only print the smallest value of the column.

In case if complete line is needed better to use `sort`:

```
sort -r -n -t [delimiter] -k[column] [file name]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ";" '(NR==1){a=$NF;b=$0} {a=$NF<a?$NF:a;b=$NF>a?b:$0} END {print b}' filename
```

this will print the line with smallest value which is encountered first.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=","}{if ( a[$1]>$2 || a[$1]=="") {a[$1]=$2;} if (b[$1]<$2) {b[$1]=$2;} } END {for (i in a) {print i,a[i],b[i]}}' input_file
```

We use `|| a[$1]==""` because when 1st value of field 1 is encountered it will have null in `a[$1]`.